# "На основе и с учётом ожиданий" — есть ли тут ошибка управления?

Tags: синтаксис, управление

Как вы считаете, есть ли в приведенном ниже примере ошибка управления? Предложение:

> Механизмы, институты и технологии, выработанные на основе и с учётом ожиданий социальных групп общества.

Смущает то, что используются разные предлоги: "на основе" и "с учётом".

Comment: Можете дать ссылку на источник?

Comment: Конечно. https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/antikrizisnyy-potentsial-publichnoy-politiki-vvedenie-v-problemu-eyo-sostoyaniya-v-regionah-rossii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибки управления нет. На основе чего? Ожиданий. С учетом чего? Ожиданий. Падежная форма слова "ожиданий" в обоих случаях соответствует необходимой.

Answer (score 0):

У меня сомнение по поводу сочетаемости слов *механизмы*, *институты* и *технологии* с глаголом *вырабатывать*.

Comment: Не вижу причин для сомнений. Но в любом случае, думаю, их следует либо аргументировать, либо вынести в отдельный вопрос (а в комментарии к этому дать ссылку на тот), либо перенести в комментарий к данному вопросу или одному из ответов.

Comment: Это всего лишь пример, который я достал из статьи Ларисы Николаевской :) Сочетаемость слов в данном случае не имеет значения.

Comment: Я задал отдельный вопрос о сочетаемости:  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447186/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b8