# Сочетаемость слов: вырабатывать механизмы, институты, технологии

Tags: лексическая-сочетаемость

У меня вызывает сомнение сочетаемость глагола *вырабатывать* со словами *механизмы*, *институты* и *технологии*.

Вопрос возник в связи с другим вопросом ([Есть ли в предложении ошибка управления?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447158/%d0%95%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)), где обсуждалось управление в предложении:

> Механизмы, институты и технологии, выработанные на основе и с учётом ожиданий социальных групп общества.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно словарю,  одним из значений глагола **выработать** является значение **"разработать"**, поэтому сочетаемость кажется **корректной.**

Текст:

В целом под публичной политикой можно понимать программы и приоритеты органов власти, а также **механизмы, институты и технологии их реализации, выработанные на основе и с учетом ожиданий социальных групп общества через их представителей.** Понимаемая таким образом публичная политика оказывается тесно связанной с понятием «общественное участие» в принятии социально значимых решений.http://www.politex.info/content/view/686/30/

**ВЫРАБОТАТЬ**,  св. что. 1. Работая, изготовить, произвести; создать, **разработать**. В. продукцию сверх плана. **В. новый метод. В. распорядок дня. В. программу действий.** //

**ИНСТИТУТ**,  м. [лат. institutum - установление, учреждение] 4. Книжн. Совокупность **норм права** в какой-л. области общественных отношений, та или иная форма общественного устройства.

Comment: Спасибо за полную цитату. Но, глядя на нее, я понимаю, что причастный оборот относится в первую  очередь к программам и приоритетам. Ведь именно они, а не механизмы их реализации  вырабатываются с учетом общественного мнения.

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, что Авторы статьи (не желая того) привязали всё перечисленное к причастному обороту, и получилось то, что получилось: в число определяемых попали ***приоритеты***, которые выбираются, ***институты***, которые подключаются, ***механизмы***, которые применяются, но никак не «вырабатываются». Нарушения связи и сочетаемости слов можно было избежать: «...приоритеты органов власти и программы институтов, механизмы их реализации, а также технологии, выработанные на основе...».