# "На основе и с учётом" — плеоназм?

Tags: плеоназм

> Механизмы, институты и технологии, выработанные на основе и с учётом ожиданий социальных групп общества.

"На основе и с учётом" — плеоназм? Ведь нельзя взять что-то за основу, не учитывая его.

И еще. "С учетом ожиданий" звучит и привычно, и логично, чего не скажу про "на основе ожиданий". Ожидания — довольно зыбкая материя, чтобы класть ее в основу. Привычно: "на основе требований".

Вопрос возник в связи с другим вопросом (["На основе и с учётом ожиданий" — есть ли тут ошибка управления?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447158/%d0%95%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)), где обсуждалось управление в предложении.

Comment: Если задаться целью, то почти в каждой фразе можно увидеть плеоназм. Любой язык избыточен.

Answer (score 2):

Я тоже обратил внимание на это выражение в том вопросе. Хотел было написать в ответе возражение, но поискал сначала другие случаи такого словоупотребления. Этих случаев оказалось довольно много, и я пришёл к выводу, что в официально-деловом стиле это один из распространённых шаблонов. В итоге я решил воспринимать выражение "на основе и с учётом ожиданий социальных групп общества..." как общепринятое сокращение более развёрнутого: "на основе некоторых ожиданий одних социальных групп общества, а также с учётом различных ожиданий других социальных групп того же общества...".